# python: loop through list of strings find index of specified element

Tags: python, list, loops

I'm sure this is simple and I'm looking right at it, but I cannot make it work.

Goal: Use a loop to go through the list of strings and find the search term. 
Return the element number of the first match.

I've tried a few options, nothing seems to work, and I have yet to find a working description of how to do it in any texts.

This is my best attempt so far:

```
def get_element_number(a_list, search_term):
    for i in range(len(a_list)):
      if search_term in a_list[i]:
        return a_list.index(i)
      elif not search_term in a_list:
        return 'no match'
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "python", line 11, in <module>
File "python", line 5, in get_element_number
ValueError: 2 is not in list
```

Not looking for the complete answer, just any help in where I'm going wrong or if I'm missing something would be very helpful.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of `a_list` and `search_term` as made in the function call?

Comment: oh sorry! get_element_number(['a'', 'b', 'd'], 'd')
I found a work around that it'll accept using the length of the list, but I definitely appreciate the help and real answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace all of this with `index = a_list.index(search_term)`.

Note that if the list doesn't contain the search_term, it will throw an exception, so you'll need to catch that and return "not found" or something similar. Second note: it only returns the first index of the found search_term.

Comment: I figured out already what to do for the exception (basically broke down the challenge into parts, solved what I could and banged my head on the desk for a bit over the rest). 
Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3):

`if search_term in a_list[i]:` is `True` even if `search_term` is *contained* in `a_list[i]`.

So in the case of an exact match `index` works, but in a case of a partial match `index` throws an exception.

Aside: `elif not search_term in a_list:` is wrong. Remove it or you'll return at first non-match.

Rewrite it as:

```
def get_element_number(a_list, search_term):
     try:
          return a_list.index(search_term)
     except IndexError:
          'no match'
```

This is simpler and has the advantage of performing search only once, which is important performance-wise when you're using linear search (not taking the overhead of exception into account).

Answer (score 0):

```
for index, s in enumerate(a_list):
  if s == term:
    return index
return -1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_element_number(a_list, search_term):
    for index, value in enumerate(a_list):
        if search_term in value:
            return index
    return 'not match'
```

Comment: I was reading about enumerate, but I thought it worked a little different. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple change to your code that will resolve it:

```
def get_element_number(a_list, search_term):
    if search_term in a_list: #if search keyword is in the list
        return a_list.index(search_term) #then return the index of that
    else:
        return 'no match!'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_element(a_list, search_term):
i = 0
for e in a_list:
    if e == search_term:
        return i
    i += 1
return -1
```

Very nice explanation for either this one or other solution you can find in the video linked below

https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=216&v=GwOFHuPMCpM

Comment: "This is if you want to be consist in for loop." isn't a grammatically correct sentence -- can you clarify?

Comment: I meant "remain consistent" as he posted the issue using for loop to solve that problem.